# Passing some parameters in OIDC redirect URI

Tags: url-encoding, openid-connect

I'm using OIDC login with AuthorizationCode flow, and everything works fine, except I have to pass some parameters in the redirect URI.

OIDC authentication tokens (code, state) are passed in POST.

In the Querystring of the redirect URI, I pass some url-encoded parameters, e.g.:

```
https://test.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&
    nonce=...&
    state=...&
    code_challenge=...&
    code_challenge_method=S256&
    client_id=...&
    scope=openid%20profile%20email%20api&
    response_mode=form_post&
    redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a60000%2fDefault.aspx%3fAppToOpen%3dA01
```

Correctly calls me back to:

```
http://localhost:60000/Default.aspx?AppToOpen=A01
```

Passing one parameter is fine, but when I send more than one:

```
https://test.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&
    nonce=...&
    state=...&
    code_challenge=...&
    code_challenge_method=S256&
    client_id=...&
    scope=openid%20profile%20email%20api&
    response_mode=form_post&
    redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a60000%2fDefault.aspx%3fAppToOpen%3dA01%26BodCode%3DSO_2
```

It redirects to this URL:

```
http://localhost:60000/Default.aspx?AppToOpen=A01&amp;BodCode=SO_2
```

As you can see, `%26` is correctly decoded to `&`, but then is encoded to `&amp;`.

How to avoid that re-encoding?

Or, is it possible to have some parameters passed in POST instead?

Comment: `&` to `&amp;` looks like html encoding, which is weird encoding for IdP. How do you testing it? Could you provide raw output from `curl` test, please?

Comment: I'll do, anyway I discovered it only happens with Auth0. Other OIDC servers correctly passes my arguments.

Comment: Anyway I solved saving the additional data in a dictionary on the server with `state` as the key.